# Debugging an iOS web app from a MacBook Air 2020 using Web Inspector

Tags: ios, macos

I want to buy the latest MacBook Air 2020 to do some small web development on Safari and especially to be able to debug my web app. (As described here for instance: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/GettingStarted/GettingStarted.html)

But I read that the latest MacBook Air have a new type of USB port. Are these backward compatible? Will I still be able to connect an iPhone to my MacBook and debug it via Web Inspector? I use a recent iPhone SE 2020 and an old iPhone 6 for testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that for recent Macs an adapter USB-C Lightning is needed.